# Why does this template function initialize a static varaible multiple times?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86

I have this following C++ code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <type_traits>

class Sample
{
    decltype(&ActivateActCtx) ActivateActCtx;
    decltype(&ReadFile) ReadFile;
    decltype(&WriteFile) WriteFile;

    template <typename F>
    static void ResolveFunction(F& output, const char* name)
    {
        static auto handle{ GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll") };
        if (!((output = reinterpret_cast<F>(GetProcAddress(handle, name)))))
            throw name;
    }

public:

    Sample()
    {
        ResolveFunction(ActivateActCtx, "ActivateActCtx");
        ResolveFunction(ReadFile, "ReadFile");
        ResolveFunction(WriteFile, "WriteFile");
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr T Get()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v < T, decltype(&::ReadFile)>)
            return ReadFile;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v < T, decltype(&::WriteFile)>)
            return WriteFile;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v < T, decltype(&::ActivateActCtx)>)
            return ActivateActCtx;

        return {};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Sample s;
    s.Get<decltype(&ReadFile)>()(nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    s.Get<decltype(&WriteFile)>()(nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    s.Get<decltype(&ActivateActCtx)>()(nullptr, nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see `auto handle{ GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll") };` is static and should be assigned with the return value of `GetModuleHandleW` just once. However, upon disassembly of the program it seems to be assigned three times, for each call in the constructor. I know that an implicit `inline` is before `ResolveFunction`, but I don't think that should literally inline so aggressively so that the definition of `static` is violated.

[image]

[image]

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 19.32.31329. Optimization settings: `/O2 /Oi /GL` I also tried maximum optimization for size and got the same result. Everything is compiled as `Release` of course.

Comment: Each call to `ResolveFunction` is with a different type, so a different instantiation of the template.  `static` local var are unique to each instance of a template function, even if the variable's own type isn't templated.

Comment: I always found that using the proper terminology _function template_ (instead of _template function_), helps to clarify expectations of behavior. It _generates_ a new function for each type based on the function template.